# In the construction of integers, is the existence of an additive inverse assumed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers

In all the constructions of the integers I've seen they seem to assume the existence of an additive inverse but I think I'm missing something because all the constructions start only with the set of natural numbers. How do negative numbers arise in the construction of integers?

Comment: It depends on what the specific construction of the integers is. There are many ways to define the group $\mathbb{Z}$ that all end up being isomorphic. The simplest way might be to define $+n$ to be the pair $(0,n)$ for $n$ a natural number and $-n$ to be $(1,n)$ for $n \geq 1$. Then define $+$ in the normal way. Basically, this is a formalization of sticking a minus sign in front of a number.

Comment: @David the constructions I've read start constructing an ordered pair and then establishing and equivalence relation

Comment: An ordered pair $(x,y)$ of two natural numbers, meant to eventually represent $x-y$?

Comment: @David and how do you get to (x,y) = x-y? That is mainly the part I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the construction you have in mind is the one described by Lee Mosher in his answer.

You can prove that each pair $(p,q)$ of natural numbers is equivalent to exactly one pair of the form $(n,0)$ or $(0,n)$. The equivalence class of the pair $(n,0)$ will play the role of the natural number $n$, and the equivalence class of the pair $(0,n)$ will play the role of $-n$.

For example, $(8,3)$ is equivalent to $(5,0)$ because $8 + 0 = 3 + 5$. The class of $(8,3)$ is the same as the class of $(5,0)$, which plays the role of $5$. On the other hand, $(2,9)$ is not equivalent to any pair of the form $(n,0)$. Instead, it is equivalent to $(0,7)$, which plays the role of $-7$.

What do I mean by "plays the role of"? There are different answers to this question depending on whether I am talking to:

- (1) someone who knows about the natural numbers but knows nothing about the integers, and wants to learn about the integers from the formal construction given; or
- (2) someone who already knows about the integers (through some other construction) and would like confirmation that the new construction corresponds to what he already knows.

In both cases, it's important to say that the classes corresponding to pairs $(n,0)$ behave the same as natural numbers under addition. What this means is that, first, no two of the pairs $(n,0)$ belong to the same equivalence class; and second, if you add the classes of $(m,0)$ and $(n,0)$, you get the class of $(m+n,0)$. For example, if you add $(5,0)$ and $(3,0)$, you get $(8,0)$, so we can say that these pairs behave exactly like the numbers $5$, $3$ and $8$.

In case (1), I would go on to prove that $\mathbb{Z}$, as constructed, is a group for $+$, and that the class of $(0,n)$ is the additive inverse of the class of $(n,0)$. For example, $(0,7) + (7,0) = (7,7) \sim (0,0)$. Thus $(0,7)$ is the additive inverse of the integer playing the role of $7$. It is fair to say that it plays the role of $-7$. (I would also show that every number is either of the form $(n,0)$, i.e. a natural number, or else its opposite.)

In case (2), my interlocutor will be interested in knowing that the newly defined operation $+$ behaves exactly like the one he knows, provided any natural number $n$ corresponds to $(n,0)$ and its opposite $-n$ corresponds to $(0,n)$. I won't give a precise statement here, but I'll illustrate this with some examples.

- $(-7) + (-4) = -11$ corresponds to $(0,7) + (0,4) = (0,11)$.
- $7 + (-4) = 3$ corresponds to $(7,0) + (0,4) = (7,4) \sim (3,0)$.
- $(-7) + 4 = - 3$ corresponds to $(0,7) + (4,0) = (4,7) \sim (0,3)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer cleared all my doubts :)

Answer (score 1):

The existence of additive inverses must be proved. Perhaps it is proved in the sources you are consulting, if you look carefully.

For example, one manner of construction of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is to use the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ where $(p,q) \sim (r,s)$ means $p+s=r+q$. The equivalence class $[p,q]$ of the ordered pair $(p,q)$ is intuitively representing what we know *a posteriori* to be the integer $p-q$. The addition operation is defined to be $[p,q] + [r,s] = [p+r,q+s]$; associativity and commutativity must be *proved*. The identity element is *proved* to be the equivalence class $[n,n]$. The additive inverse of $[p,q]$ is *proved* to be $[q,p]$.

**Added to answer the question in the comments:** The meaning of *a posteriori* in this situation is *after the construction is completed*.

So, after $\mathbb{Z}$ has been constructed, and after all the proofs are complete, including the proof that $[q,p]$ is the additive inverse of $[p,q]$, there are a few steps to identifying $[p,q]$ with $p-q$.

First, one shows that the map $i : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $i(n) = [n,0]$ is an "embedding" of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$, meaning an injection which preserves the operation of addition in the sense that $i(n+m)=i(n)+i(m)$. I am assuming here that $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$; but if instead one wishes to use $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ then the embedding can be defined by $i(n)=[n+1,1]$.

Using this embedding, the natural number $n$ is identified with the integer $[n,0]$, which I will write as $n \sim [n,0]$.

Second, one proves that $[0,n] = -[n,0]$, where the $-$ symbol means "additive inverse".

Third, using the identifications $p \sim [p,0]$ and $q \sim [q,0]$ one obtains
$$p - q \sim [p,0] - [q,0] = [p,0] + (-[q,0]) = [p,0] + [0,q] = [p,q]
$$

Comment: and how do you get to [p,q] = p-q? I've seen they get there using a bit of algebra subtracting in both sides of the equation, but they are indeed assuming that an additive inverse exists (if I'm not mistaken)